# Maven error with Java 8

Tags: java, maven, java-8

Getting an error with Maven and Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_45). This issue does not occur with Java 7.

**MCVE**

Create a sample maven project. For example:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=testinovke -DartifactId=testinvoke
```

Create the following content in the generated App.java file

```
package testinovke;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class App {

    public static MethodHandles.Lookup lookup;

    public static class Check {
        public void primitive(final int i){
        }
        public void wrapper(final Integer i){
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Check check = new Check();

        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class);

        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(Check.class, "primitive", type);
        mh.invoke();
    }
}
```

Compile the maven project:

```
mvn clean compile
```

**Output**

Get the following error:

```
testinvoke/src/main/java/testinovke/App.java:[25,18] method invoked with incorrect number of arguments; expected 0, found 1
```

Tried it with both Maven 3.0.4 and 3.3.3.
This issue does not exist if I directly compile against App.java using Javac command.

Comment: Works here using Java 1.8.0_45 and  Maven 3.2.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add plugin configuration for the compiler:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can't accept answer as stackoverflow makes we wait 10 mins!. Will accept later.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is adding these properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

to your `pom.xml`, and the plugins will pick these up automatically.